# Sending automatic email to email address based on cell value in row

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to send automatic email from Excel though Outlook subject to the condition that the value in a column is greater than 2, and retrieve specific cells from the same row in which the conditions is true.

Furthermore, how can I send it to an email address saved in one of the cells within that row?

```vb
Dim xRg As Range
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/3/7
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("D7:D1000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 2 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "Email Address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "send by cell value test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `Target.Row` so if email address is in column A `.To = Cells(Target.Row,"A")`

Comment: is that your solution ?

Comment: You also need too pass `Target` to the email sub or use the global `xRg` instead.

Comment: @CDP1802, could you please explain that by editing my codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
    With xOutMail
        .To = Cells(xRg.Row,"A") ' column A
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "send by cell value test"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
```

Comment: But what is the universal code before the above codes ?

Comment: @Ahmed Use same code as you have but replace the line `.To = "Email Address"` with `.To = Cells(xRg.Row,"C") ` if the email address is in column C.

Comment: Thanks ! I have done exactly what you said , but it doesn't work .

Comment: @Ahmed  comment out the line `On Error Resume Next` and see what error you get

Comment: I have removed this line , and en error message saying :Object doesn't support this property or method . Please advise

Comment: @Ahmed You have to give more detail, which line is the error on. Single step the program with F8.

Comment: The line .To = Cells(xRg.Row,"C") is not working . My goal is once the working days is more than 2 days in column Q , the reminder message will be sent to the email of the sales agent written in column C within the same row C . Please @CDP1802 advise

Comment: @Ahmed Your code runs when a change is made in column D `xRg = Intersect(Range("D7:D1000"), Target)` and that is the column you are checking with `And Target.Value > 2 Then` not Q.

Comment: @  CDP1802 ,  Yes thats True , I wrongly written Q , while the write one is D .

Comment: @ CDP1802 , but it is still I want to send the email in the column "C" when the condition is true on the column D .

Comment: @Ahmed Where have you put the code, on a worksheet, workbook or module ? It needs to go on the same sheet as the data.

Comment: @ CDP1802, I have created the code on the same data sheet , and to prove that all the codes are working properly except our code related to "Send To" . please advise

Comment: @Ahmed Do you mean it works with `.To = "Email Address"` but not with `.To = Cells(xRg.Row,"C")` ? If not working , does it raise an error if so what error and which line ? How are you testing it ? You need to trigger the sub by changing the value in the range D7:D1000 to greater than 2"

Comment: @ CDP1802  , it works if write manually the email into Send To ; however, it doesn't work with the code .To = Cells(xRg.Row,"C") which I need it to work